# WebStorm debugging and subsequent clicks

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, webstorm

I have a back button in my Ionic Framework application, and it's moving too quickly due to Ionic's removal of the browser lag that usually accompanies browsers inputs.

This leads my app to allow really fast clicking of buttons, and causing strange behaviors.

If I land a break point, I cannot debug properly because the first click gets 'caught' by the breakpoint.  I want to write a timeout that fixes this problem but it's hard to debug/test.  Ideas?

Comment: Sounds very bizzare that clicking a button really quickly would cause bugs. In my opinion, that indicates that your click handlers are running stuff on non-UI background threads? If it's a single-threaded application then your UI will 'lock' until the next click. If you're doing background stuff then I'd recommend temporarily locking the click method until the background stuff completes.

Comment: Also, I'm aware that I'm not answering your question at all with that one, it's just that I've experienced similar wierd stuff and it's usually when the UI is launching bizzare race conditions.

Comment: @AdamKewley Ionic framework has some changes that make it 'feel' snappier.. one of them is remove the input delays from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webstorm seems to support [conditional breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/breakpoints-2.html), so you could introduce something like a counter into your code:

```
 var i = 0;

 theButton.click(function()
 {
     i++;

     // Your code here, put a conditional breakpoint in, such as 
     // mod 5'ing i so you can see the program state every 5th click
     // for example.
 }
```

Bit of a hacky approach, but it might give you what you need.